# How to reload the page without reloading it ,letz assume the content to be displayed is large

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I want to develop a web page where the page details need to be updated for some particular time without hitting the reload button, how can I achieve this I'm using angular for front end and backend spring boot? Any Suggestions?

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried and add some code.

Comment: Have a look to websocket : https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

It will allow the back to send message directly to the front, with this you can either display the data directly or trigger a get to the backk to load bigger data